# How do I print currency format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, formatting, numbers, currency

I have some price values to display in my page.

I am writing a function that takes the float price and returns the formatted currency value with currency code too.

> like fnPrice(`1001.01`) should print `$ 1,000.01`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format numbers as currency string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to do this by hand, there is nothing builtin into JS. For an example look at this post here: [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Comment: Sorry, you're right, the comment would have been enough. Thanks for fixing , now you've got an upvote!

Answer (score 22):

You can using code :

```
function formatMoney(number) {
  return number.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
}

console.log(formatMoney(10000));   // $10,000.00
console.log(formatMoney(1000000)); // $1,000,000.00
```

It was answered at [Javascript Function to Format as Money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426965/javascript-function-to-format-as-money)

Or you can custom :

```
function formatMoney(number) {
   return '$ '+ number.toLocaleString('en-US');
}
```